# Setting Server Variables before Apache Loads

Tags: centos, apache-2.2, environment-variables, env

We have CentOS with Apache running on it. Basically, I have a few variables in /etc/environment and they're passed through to our Apache configs using PassEnv. The issue is that because Apache is before /etc/environment the variables are not found.

Is there a similar kind of /etc/environment file that I can add my global environmental variables into that is executed before apache (httpd) or do I have to start editing runlevels?

Kind regards,

Steve

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well. I'm not convinced that CentOS uses `/etc/environment` at all. A [search on redhat.com](http://www.redhat.com/search?q=%2Fetc%2Fenvironment&site=redhat&btnG=Search&getfields=title&client=external&proxyreload=0&proxystylesheet=external&output=xml_no_dtd&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&entqr=3&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1) and a search on RedHat's Kbase returns nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Use "/etc/sysconfig/httpd" to set Apache environment.

Comment: I would like the environmental variables to be accessible from the command line too, as there are some PHP scripts that we use that need those variables.

Comment: For those using Debian/Ubuntu, the file to edit is `/etc/apache2/envvars`

Comment: this does not work on aws ec2

Answer (score 5):

If these are variables which apply to each and every user on the system, then they should be added in /etc/enviornment - but IIRC this file is not explicitly parsed by the init scripts.

So you'd need to add a line in /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions, e.g.

```
# -*-Shell-script-*-
#
# functions     This file contains functions to be used by most or all
#               shell scripts in the /etc/init.d directory.
# 
# amended to set env vars

TEXTDOMAIN=initscripts

. /etc/environment
```

However if you only want these vars to be available to the webserver, then they should be declared in /etc/sysconfig/httpd, e.g.

```
# Configuration file for the httpd service.

export MYSQL_USER = mydbuser
```

(might work without the explicit export).

Comment: Looks like the best solution so far... although I'm surprised that a file such as /etc/environment or something similar is not parsed early during the init process. Am I approaching this problem from the wrong angle?

Comment: Trying /etc/sysconfig/httpd myself, it didn't seem to make the vars available to a bash script running as apache until I added `export` like you showed here.