# setting and working webserver environment variables

Tags: httpd, centos5, environment-variables

currently I'm trying to setup environment variables for Apache in CentOS 5.5

According with CentOS manual and [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/233204/setting-server-variables-before-apache-loads) they should be placed in **/etc/sysconfig/httpd** but doing that I get *Undefined index **myvar***

**env_module** is enabled so that's not the problem.

So exactly how do I setup such variables for HTTP access only?

Regards

Comment: Tell us *exactly* what you added to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and where you are seeing the error.

Comment: there is no error but is not taking defined variables for webserver.

I added some variables to use as $_SERVER['MY_VAR']:

export MY_VAR=value1